# React Redux connecting state to props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to set up a store for a react app, I'm having trouble connecting the store to a component. I've had a look at the official examples but can't see where I'm going wrong.

`Cannot read property 'app' of undefined`

In `app.js` it says `state` is undefined, my understanding is that `Provider` passes this down. I'm not sure if i'm overlooking something simple but I'm currently stumped.

EDIT: I've now added all files involved.

`root.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from '../configureStore';
import App from './app';

const store = configureStore();

export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

`app.js`

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchFixtures } from '../actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    fixtures: state.app.fixtures
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div></div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

`configureStore.js`

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import Reducer from './reducers';

let initialState = {
  app: {
    teams: [],
    fixtures: [],
    manifesto: []
  }
}

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStore(
    Reducer,
    initialState
  )
}
```

`actions.js`

```
export function fetchFixtures(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => dispatch(recieveFixtures(json)))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

function recieveFixtures(json) {
  return {
    type: ADD_FIXTURES,
    fixtures: json.fixtures.map(fixture => fixture)
  }
}
```

`reducers.js`

```
function euroSweep(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_FIXTURES':
      let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default euroSweep;
```

`index.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import Root from './containers/root';

render(
  <Root />, document.querySelector('.app')
)
```

Comment: Where is `state` undefined?  In `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: @DavinTryon Yes, state is undefined when passing it to `mapStateToProps`

Comment: what does `configureStore` look like?  What reducer is producing `fixtures`?

Comment: I think you are missing the initialState even in the reducer

Comment: Looks like you are defining an `app` key in state that you are not taking into account.  Try: fixtures: `state.app.fixtures`.  Can't see anything else obviously wrong.

Comment: @DavinTryon Ah, updated the code but the state object is undefined, it seems state just isn't available in `app.js`

Comment: If you `console.log`: `store` after `const store = configureStore()`, what do you get?

Comment: @DavinTryon ```Object {}
dispatch
:
dispatch(action)
getState
:
getState()
replaceReducer
:
replaceReducer(nextReducer)
subscribe
:
subscribe(listener)
Symbol(observable)
:
observable()
__proto__
:
Object```

Comment: OK, I assume that when you render with `ReactDom` you are rendering the `Root` Component, right?

Comment: @DavinTryon Yes I have an `index.js` file (i've added it to the question) which renders the root component

Comment: Your `initialState` seems to be undefined since you are calling `configureStore` with no arguments. This overrides the local variable in the upper scope. Assign a default parameter or remove the parameter of `configureStore`.

Comment: @Herku add it as an answer as that was the problem, I figured it out before but i'll accept it!